# Search doesn't say how many results there are anymore

Tags: bug, status-completed, search

Before, there was something that said how many search results there are, like this:

> [image]

I took the above screenshot from [this bug report](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/303174/323179), which means it was there two days ago at least.

But now, there is no "*n* results" text to tell you how many results there are:

> [image]

Please fix this; I liked knowing how many results I was getting.

Comment: I need this too; I used it often to determine which of two synonymous terms is used more often in mathematics. Don't want to scroll down to the page count.

Comment: We'll take a look at this, bear with us as we make updates to search this month and next. I'm not 100% sure *this* removal was intentional, but things like extremely high paging (due to performance underneath) we'll need to find alternatives for. Elasticsearch has made many changes we're not really happy with and we're seeing how best to change our usage of their available functionality now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Missed this, it will be coming back in the next deploy.