# Chat search results limited to 9999 items

Tags: bug, chat, chat-search

So, to put it another way, chat search will return results with 200+ pages but only the first 199 pages have content.

Today I was looking for some really early messages about myself in a room I use but I found that I'd been mentioned in the room more than 50*199 times (9950 mentions) and that any mentions that appeared further back in time than what filled those first 199 pages were simply blank - the content I wanted is currently on page 201, so it's tantalizingly close.

If you manually change the number of results per page to 1 (by editing the URL) and look at page 9,999, you can actually get most of the content of page 200 (if viewed at 50 items per page). So, it seems that attempting to serve result number 10,000 (or higher) breaks the search results pages.

That said, this information wasn't lost to time. When I refined my results by who said it, the earlier messages come up just fine. It's purely a matter of too many results.

Can chat search please enable my navel-gazing by populating all returned pages?

As an example, [here's what you get](https://chat.stackexchange.com/search?q=napoleonwilson&room=1888) when you search "napoleonwilson" in the Screening Room. 473 pages of results but when you go to any page after 199 (when viewing 50 results per page), say [317](https://chat.stackexchange.com/search?q=napoleonwilson&Room=1888&page=317&pagesize=50&sort=newest), there's no content on the page.

Is there a reason that this is limited? Can it be fixed?

Comment: My original title was better. :(

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/303174/no-more-than-10000-results-are-visible-in-search

Comment: @Shog9 Seems to be the same, I'm just going by page count rather than total results... though, it's not quite 10,000... page 200 doesn't work, and I don't think my math is off?

Comment: Main site search vs. chat search; probably an off-by-one error in chat somewhere. Note that you can get all the way to 9,999 results [if you change the page size](https://chat.stackexchange.com/search?q=napoleonwilson&Room=1888&page=9999&pagesize=1&sort=newest) (also note the *other* off-by-one error...).

Comment: That said, I'm gonna call this status-norepro, since [I was able to get results on page 10,000](https://chat.stackexchange.com/search?q=eggs&page=10000&pagesize=50&sort=newest)

Comment: So, apparently page size=1 returns two items per page?

Comment: thanks to your original title I have learned an interesting new phrase :p